# How to save currently logged in user username in domain class?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to create new instance of a domain class with one field witch will be the username of currently logged in user. I'm using Spring security & Spring Security UI. Please give me some code example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get to the currently logged user, you can use dependency injection in your controller to get access to the springSecurityService, and from there, currently logged in user's username.

```
def springSecurityService // will be injected by DI

... in controller method,

    def currentUsername = new MyDomainClassWithUsername(springSecurityService.currentUser.username)        
    currentUsername.save()
```

Comment: This is the error that I get:   Error 500: Executing action [create] of controller [com.test.IncidentController] caused exception: No such property: username for class: org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationToken

Comment: I'm trying to get the username of the Spring Security User class.

Comment: try: springSecurityService.getCurrentUser().username

Comment: Also my main question was, when I get the value of username, how to save in database? Other values are entered trough form and passed to controller via params object. Do I also use params for this? If the property in the table I want to save data is called startedBy do I do something like this:  params.startedBy = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser().username

Comment: Saving to database is done via domain classes. Params are for setting your domain classes properties. You can set your domain class property explicitly. I guess you could set a param, and then set domain class properties from params, but it seems convoluted. Please paste sources for your controller method, and domain class.

Comment: This will work, assuming you have a field named 'startedBy' in your Incident class. A cleaner way to do this would be not to change params, but call `incidentInstance.startedBy = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser().username` after incidentInstance creation.

Comment: Sory, but I cant seam to format my code normally. Both options work.But binding over the incident instance is more natural. Thank you.